# Html parse with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

```
<div>
<div class = "main">
    <div class ="content">
        <div class="content_left">
            <div class="alisveris_context_box">
                <ul class = "sinema_list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="blabla/12" title="asd">
                            <img src="http://asd.jpg">
                            <span class ="cartoon">
                                Textaa
                            </span>
```

How can I get the `href` value (`blabla/12` in the example) and `span` value (`Textare` in the example)?

Comment: Maybe you calm down for a second and checkout the Stackover flow help center to figure what makes up a good question. Hint: what you provided here exactly does not. And making you aware of that is not **trolling**. If you want to be treated with more respect; well, then, surprise: you ought to treat this community with the same respect. And in fact you are not doing that. As "asking for advise before doing anything else" is clearly **not** what you should do when coming to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your html is the follow.

```
 String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element link = doc.select("a").first();

    String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
```

link.attr("href") will have your link.

Same for your span. Think for yourself :)

source: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Comment: This is just my suggestion. But you should always read the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jsoup you can easily find out
You will get span value by this

```
String st="<div> <div class = \"main\">     <div class =\"content\">        "
            + "<div class=\"content_left\">  <div class=\"alisveris_context_box\">"
            + "   <ul class = \"sinema_list\">  <li>  <a href=\"blabla/12\" title=\"asd\">"
            + "<img src=\"http://asd.jpg\">  <span class =\"cartoon\">     Textaa           </span>";
String spanValue=Jsoup.parse(st).text();
```

and href value by

```
String href=Jsoup.parse(st).getElementsByTag("a").attr("href");
```

Comment: what is st? Is it the html?

Comment: sorry I missed that portion   'String st="<div> <div class = \"main\">     <div class =\"content\">        "
    + "<div class=\"content_left\">  <div class=\"alisveris_context_box\">"
    + "   <ul class = \"sinema_list\">  <li>  <a href=\"blabla/12\" title=\"asd\">"
    + "<img src=\"http://asd.jpg\">  <span class =\"cartoon\">     Textaa           </span>";'

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements elements = Jsoup.parse(html).select("div[class=main] div[class=content] div[class=content_left] div[class=alisveris_context_box] ul[class=sinema_list] li a");

String href = elements.first().attr("href");
String spanText = elements.first().select("span[class=cartoon]").first().text();
```